# Show that if K is any knot in regular position there is an alternating knot (in regular position) that has the same projection as K.

Tags: proof-writing, geometric-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Show that if K is any knot in regular position there is an alternating knot (in regular position) that has the same projection as K.

Could anyone give me a hint for solving this please?

Comment: Have you tried taking a specific knot diagram then modifying its crossings until you have an alternating knot?

Comment: No I will try thank you for the hint